# Which free deployment/installer software is better?

Tags: setup-deployment

Which of the following free deployment/installer software is better:

- Inno Setup
- AdvancedInstaller

Does Microsoft offer free deployment/installer software with the same capabilities as the above?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio you can add a Setup Project to your existing solution.  You can customize each step of the setup and include custom actions and prerequisites.

You can create the following setups:

- Merge Module
- Setup (MSI)
- Web Setup
- CAB files

Full information on the MS Visual Studio Setup & Deployment Project can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx)

Comment: the software I am deploying is a hybrid VB6/.NET product so I need something where I can specify exactly what I want to happen.